# Command"phonegap build android" failed

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, phonegap-build, build.gradle

I tried to build an existing android-phonegap file using "phonegap build android", it failed and showed some errors. But, I have built a new android-phonegap file successfully using the same command. Why does it not build the existing file? I have searched some answers online, those didn't work. I have changed minsdkversion and targetsdkversion in Androidmainfest.xml and build.grade, this still didn't work.

**Here are the errors:**

> :processDebugManifest
>   /Users/zhangxu/Desktop/Rouse Services Modified/rmpa/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:15:13 Error:
>
> Missing one of the key attributes 'action#name,category#name' on element intent-filter at AndroidManifest.xml:15:13
>
> /Users/zachary/Desktop/phohegapProject/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
>   Error:
>
> Validation failed, exiting
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: 
>   Build failed with an exception.

*** What went wrong:**

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

*** Try:**

> Run with
>   --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or
>   --debug
>    option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.064 secs
>
> /Users/zachary/desktop/phonegapProject/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                      throw e;
>                             ^
>   Error code 1 for command:
>   /Users/zachary/desktop/phonegapProject/platforms/android/gradlew with args:  cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/zachary/desktop/phonegapProject/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>
> ERROR building one of the platforms: Error:
>   /Users/zachary/desktop/phonegapProject/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>
> Error: /Users/zachary/desktop/phonegapProject/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

Comment: did you find the answer to this ? I've ran into the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the plugin:

com.synconset.imagepicker

and this seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try uninstalling the platform and installing it again ?

Answer (score 0):

I know is a late answer, but this maybe help someone else with the issue.

when building with build.phonegap add this to your config.xml:

```
<plugin name="com.synconset.imagepicker" spec="https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git"/>
```